# How to extend Landy react app to navigate to a new page using Router model

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want help to update Landy out of the box application https://github.com/Adrinlol/landy-react-template

In a normal react /javascript model I would have written like the below

```
<Route path='/thanks' exact element={<ProtectedRoute><ThankyouPage/></ProtectedRoute>} />
<Route path='/revised' exact element={<ProtectedRoute><ThankyouEditPage/></ProtectedRoute>} />
```

But the template is more functional and I don't know how to customize this typescript model

```
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Router />
    </I18nextProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

> 

```
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Styles />
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        {routes.map((routeItem) => {
          return (
            <Route
              key={routeItem.component} path={routeItem.path} exact={routeItem.exact}
              component={lazy(() => import(`../pages/${routeItem.component}`))}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

How can I add a new Route and where ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out, added new path /test similar to Home and created a Test folder with index.tsx

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: ["/", "/home"],
    exact: true,
    component: "Home",
  },
  {
    path: ["/test"],
    exact: true,
    component: "Test",
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Button action integration

```
  const testPage = () => {
    history.push("/test");
  };
```

> `< Button onClick={testPage}>{t("Test")}< /Button>`